# How to add external framework to system library during launching of Mac application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have Created a mail server using pantomime framework.My Appliction is running only in condition when
i add pantomime Framework mannualy to /Libarary/Framework/ path of system.
When i delete these framework from that path then my application crashed
Is there any buildsetting in xcode are any other way to resolve these problem.
Please provide me any suggestion. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a copy files build phase to the target which copies the framework to the Frameworks destination.